# RXJS listen to first subscription

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have a function that wraps observable with error handling, but to do so I need some code to run once it's inner observable is subscribed.

I also need that cancelling the higher `Observable` cancels the inner one, as it is doing HTTP call.

Context

```
slideshow: string[] = [];
currentIndex = 0;
private is = {
    loading: new BehaviorSubject(false),
}

private loadImage(src: string): Observable;

private loadNextImage(index = this.currentIndex, preload = false): Observable<number> {
    const nextIndex = (index + 1) % this.slideshow.length;
        if (this.currentIndex == nextIndex) {
        if (!preload) {
            this.is.loading.next(false);
        }
        throw new Error('No other images are valid');
    }

    return ( possible code below )
}
```

`Defer` - This worked nicely until I realised this will create a new instance for every subscriber.

```
defer(() => {
    if (!preload) {
        this.is.loading.next(true);
    }
    return this.loadImage(this.slideshow[nextIndex]).pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            if (!preload) {
                this.is.loading.next(false);
            }
        }),
        map(() => nextIndex),
        catchError(err => this.loadNextImage(nextIndex)),
    );
});
```

`Of(void 0).pipe(mergeMap(...))` - This does what is should, but it is really ugly

```
of(void 0).pipe(
    mergeMap(() => {
        if (!preload) {
            this.is.loading.next(true);
        }

        return this.loadImage(this.slideshow[nextIndex]).pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                if (!preload) {
                    this.is.loading.next(false);
                }
            }),
            map(() => nextIndex),
            catchError(err => this.loadNextImage(nextIndex)),
        );
    }),
)
```

`new Observable` - I think there should be a solution that I am missing

Comment: `defer` in combination with `shareReplay` should do it. Use the refCount setting to unsubscribe from source once all subscribers are gone (needs v6.4)

Comment: @ggradnig But that would mean adding two kinda heavy pipes, the `of` & `mergemap` might be easier here

Comment: You're right, but anything other than `share` will create new instances for each subscriber.

Comment: @ggradnig Even the `of(void 0).pipe(mergeMap(...))` construct?

Comment: Yes, every Observable except the multicast ones behave that way. Notice though, that your HTTP framework might have included a caching mechanism that makes this less obvious.

Comment: @ggradnig Do you have something reading upon this? Also if you make this into an answer I would love to accept your answer.